# Hyphen in custom HTML-tags

Tags: html

I want to use custom tags at my page.
[I've read](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/04/custom-element-semantics/) that custom tags must contain a hyphen like this: `<my-element></my-element>`.
What will happen if I call my tags without hyphen: `<myelement></myelement>`?
Will it affect the search engines or other consequences?

Comment: Pretty sure the better way is to actually namespace it. For instance, `<mysite:element />` - namespacing makes it basically impossible to accidentally override an existing obscure tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it is not a requirement "because otherwise doesn't work". Maybe that advice is just to ensure you don't override a legacy tag and get puzzled with the fact something works in the way it's not documented.

There's definitely no problem with defining, styling and doing something via js with a tag without hyphens at all and I've practiced it and had no issue. Neither vanilla javascript nor jQuery cares about hyphens in your tags.

As for search engines - it would be very weird if search engines take account of the fact whether the tag contains the hyphen at all or not. It's like saying "will search engine penalise my page if my javascript doesn't work correctly", i.e. something that search engine is not supposed to check at all. The hyphens are just about your coding coding habits - use them if you like them.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a living standard.  That means it is not versioned and new tags can be added at any time.  For this reason, if you add your own tag, say `<calendar>`, and later that is added to the specification, browsers will start to treat that tag in accordance with the specification.

So making your own tag without a dash does not conform to HTML specification.  It's likely that it will work just fine in the vast majority of browsers, but it is possible that it may cause issues down the line or may cause search engines to lower the rank of your page.

There's absolutely no reason not to put that dash in there.